# Does Vuetify 3 support tables and tabs?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I am working with Vuetify 3 (alpha.12) and can't find in [official site](https://next.vuetifyjs.com/en/getting-started/installation)  -> Components information about tables and tabs. At the same time Vuetify 2 supported them. So the question, does Vuetify 3 support them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The vuetify is still under development and there're many components which have not been supported yet like:

- Data table
- Tabs
- Carousel
- Form inputs

You could read the note in home page :

> Before proceeding, it is important to note that this installation is intended primarily for testing purposes, and should not be considered for production applications.